# Give the differential and the derivative of $f(X) = I − X(X^tX)^{-1}X^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

I don't know what to do, maybe use the product rule. Give the differential and the derivative of the function
$$f(X) = I − X(X^tX)^{-1}X^t $$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

Here $X,H\in M_{n,m}$ where $m\leq n$ and $rank(X)=m$. Note that $f$ is a product of $3$ functions $u,v,w$ ; then the derivative of $f$ is $Duvw+uvDw+uDvw$, that is,

$Df_X:H\rightarrow -H(X^TX)^{-1}X^T-X(X^TX)^{-1}H^T+X(X^TX)^{-1}(H^TX+X^TH)(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$. The previous result is different from that of martini.